# Rails: asset pipeline is not persisted. Changes in CSS do not appear in browser

Tags: css, browser

I am working on an app in Rails. We are using Turbolinks. 
I've had this issue since yesterday : **changes in CSS or JS do not appear in the browser** (Chrome). 
So far, the only way to see changes is to run "rake asset:clean" and "rake assets:precompile" in the terminal, for any modification.

I used hard-refresh (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), but it didn't work.
I also tracked what was happening in the network while hard-refreshing : 
-"status" in 200, and "size" is 66.3KB. 
I cleared the cache of my browser.

Does anyone know how to fix this asset pipeline issue, so I no longer have to manually update changes ?

Answer (score 1):

I cracked the case with my good friend and beloved CEO @bonapara : just DON'T RUN "rake assets:precompile". This is the source of the problem.

Check your public folder in your app, delete the "assets" folder. Here you are.